# How to make two git repos the same

Tags: git, gitlab

I have two git repos with same code on two separate gitlab deployments. It is not gitlab EE so i dont have the mirror functionality available to me.

In the beginning I ensured that each commit is pushed to both repos but over time it got out of hands and i could do justice to this practice.

At the moment I would forcefully like to make `repo1` the same as `repo2`. But while doing this I seem to be stuck in a circle.

This is what I do:

```
$ git pull repo1 master
...there are conflicts. 
...I resolve them, add the file, then do git rebase --continue
$ git push repo1 master --now this works
$ git pull repo2 master
...there are conflicts. 
...I resolve them, add the file, then do git rebase --continue
$ git push repo2 master
```

After the above, I would imagine everything is ok. But now when I do `git pull repo1 master`, I have to do the above steps over again.

**Question**

Is there a way to forcefully make `repo1` the same as `repo2` other than deleting repo1 from gitlab and starting over?

Additionally, going forward what would be the best way to keep both repos in-sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it really necessary to have those 2 exact equal repos?
If yes, it would be easier to push only to repo1 from local and then push to repo2 from repo1 (for example with a git post-receive hook)

But for now you could try `force push` (**git push -f**) to overwrite the commit history in repo1. (Assuming repo2 contains the "correct" history and repo1 the wrong one):

```
$ git pull repo2 master
... if there are conflicts, take versions from remote (repo2)
$ git push -f repo1 master
```

Answer (score 0):

From repo1:

```
git remote add repo2 <path to the other repo>
git checkout master
git fetch repo2
git reset --hard repo2/master
```

Do this for every branch you'd be interested in making the same (probably just master and a develop branch?).